# Sample size question / margin of error

Tags: statistics, sampling

I'm a complete novice in this area - so "explaining to me like I'm 5" would be most appreciated.

Essentially, I've been tasked with changing the a relevancy algorithm for products displayed on a website - which is fine...

The 'quality' metric is how users rate the product - there are four states:

```
Suitable, Maybe, Unsuitable, Pending
```

Each day - There are approximately 100 ratings/day - and as the products age, their rating-counts increase - but broadly, the ratios stay consistent as time goes by - but there is a slight variance day-by-day.

My question:
Upon making a change to the algorithm, what is the minimum sample size (length of time I have to run the test) before I can be sure I have a statistically significant result? How can I be confidant that any change I make is positive - and not just within some margin of error?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion, why not pick a few products and establish your own significance point as follows;

1. Take a product and graph the rating over time, (so rating on the y axis and number of ratings on the x axis)

What you'll typically find is that the line you plot will start off busy, and converge onto a steady rating.

Typically, the smallest number of observations required to create a normal distribution will be 20.  Hence, you will likely find that after 20 observations, your average rating will not be significantly different from 50 or 100 ratings.

I hope this helps.

regards
Marcus